# Extract and repack miner firmware

Tags: linux-kernel

i would like to know how to extract a miner firmware and translate the www folder and change logo,
file command return :

> gzip compressed data, was "blah3.tar", last modified: Mon Jan 15 04:57:44 2018, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 12462080

then extracted using tar xzvf command and there is "initramfs.bin.SD" file within extracted files file command return

> u-boot legacy uImage, Angstrom-antminer_m-eglibc-ipk-v\037\213\010, Linux/ARM, RAMDisk Image (gzip), 12435650 bytes, Mon Jan 15 04:57:13 2018, Load Address: 00000000, Entry Point: 00000000, Header CRC: 0X92E36810, Data CRC: 0XC2FBA44D

i dont know what to do next

i would be very thankful if someone would give me a how to

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

You just send a polite email to the vendor making this hardware. They shipped you a Linux image, which means they're bound by the GPL, and are legally required to give you all the source and tooling required to build a bootable image. (They're not required to give you the source code of the software running on top of that Linux, if it's not GPL; the kernel license has an exception to that; but the boot image is clearly a composite work containing the Linux kernel, which is GPL.)

Then, they send you back an email, a link, a DVD, a USB drive or whatever containing the source code of the exact Linux kernel you're running, and whatever else is needed to compose that bootable image of the existing files.

That will allow you to build an image yourself.